# iOS Swift : How to detect that other apps are being use by the user or not?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Suppose I launched my app and kept it is in background by pressing home button and now user is started using their other apps (like WhatsApp, Instagram, Paytm etc any apps) .

My requirement is that I need to detect that user is using their phone to use any other app or not.

Answer (score 2):

In short, your requirements are malicious since this would be a huge security breach.

You cannot access other applications, you cannot even check they are installed unless they support it themselves.

The only possibility is having a jailbroken iPhone, that is, an iPhone with security measures turned off and direct (hacked) access to system functionality.

Comment: I understand, In one of my apps, I need to track the phone uses time by user when my app is in background (i.e. home button pressed). Please let me know if any alternative available to achieve this.

Comment: What you desire is impossible. You will need to redesign so that you don't need it. The user (or parent in a Family Sharing situation) may use the Screen Time system to determine this information. Your app cannot. Your app may submit information to Screen Time, but it cannot read it, and it cannot acquire it itself (outside of jailbroken phones as Sulthan notes).

Comment: Also you can't run your app in the background as you are describing. Once you move it to the background it'll stop running (there are some background modes, but you can't use these to run continuously)